# Need to declare a cursor with a variable in the declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a problem with a maintenance procedure and need to create a second one where I declare a cursor with a list of database ID and pass them into another cursor to get a list of tables for each database.

Current problem is that in the inner cursor even though it runs use [database_name], when i declare it and specify my query it selects the tables from the master database. it doesn't change the database context before going into the inner cursor.

```
DECLARE @db varchar(128) 
declare @cmd varchar(1024)
declare @table varchar(255)
declare @cmd2 varchar(1024)

   DECLARE crDB CURSOR global FORWARD_only FOR
   SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4
   and database_id in (33) ORDER BY [name]

   OPEN crDB
   FETCH crDB INTO @db
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN 
   SET @cmd = 'USE [' + @db +']'
   EXEC (@cmd)


           DECLARE crTB CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
           select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'u' ORDER BY [name]
           OPEN crTB
           FETCH crTB INTO @table
           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN
           SET @cmd2 = 'Update Statistics ' + @table + CHAR(13) 
           PRINT @cmd2
           EXEC (@cmd2)
           end
           CLOSE crTB
           DEALLOCATE crTB

    FETCH crDB INTO @db
    END
    CLOSE crDB
    DEALLOCATE crDB
```

GO

Comment: [This will solve this issue, and so many more](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html). It's ola hallengren's maintenance solution. It's free, well documented, and open source. It'll save you hours, and is portable across every supported build of SQL Server.

Comment: @scsimon was just about to post the same. Here is STRONG second for not doing this yourself.

Comment: I know about the Ola, but in this case there was an application update which created columnstore indexes and I began to get errors with sp_updatestats. So I took my script and looking to change it to run update statistics instead.    I like to write my own stuff just for my own practice.

Comment: you are only updating stats... that's what the `@UpdateStatistics` parameter for his scripts are for... so you can *only* do that if you want. what does this have to do with columnstore?

Comment: a columnstore index was added to a database and this error began to pop up with sp_updatestats. I tested using Update Statistics statement and it works, but I want to make it so that if I have multiple databases i can use the same procedure        UPDATE STATISTICS failed because statistics cannot be updated on a columnstore index.  UPDATE STATISTICS is valid only when used with the STATS_STREAM option.

Comment: I think that the USE statement will only affect the batch executed in the EXEC statement, so you will have to place the code for the inner cursor inside the `@cmd` variable.

Comment: I'd add bug then: https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues since his script uses sp_updatestats. Be sure you aren't using ONLINE. That feature request has been put in: https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/178

Comment: The `USE` reverts to the original database context after the dynamic sql command completes. You could just use 3-part names: `SET @cmd2 = 'Update Statistics ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + '.dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@table);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your inner cursor, is scope. You can to do 2 things here. You have to move your inner cursor to right after the `USE [' + @db` like:

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @cmd2 VARCHAR(1024);

DECLARE crDB CURSOR GLOBAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4
  AND database_id IN (33)
ORDER BY name;

OPEN crDB;

FETCH crDB
INTO @db;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
  SET @cmd = 'USE [' + @db + ']
    GO;
  DECLARE crTB CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT name
  FROM sys.objects
  WHERE type = ''u'';
  ORDER BY name;

  OPEN crTB;

  FETCH NEXT FROM crTB
  INTO @table;

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @cmd2 = ''Update Statistics '' + @table + CHAR(13);

    PRINT @cmd2;

    EXEC (@cmd2);
    END;    

  CLOSE crTB;
  DEALLOCATE crTB;
    ';

  EXEC (@cmd);

  FETCH NEXT FROM crDB
  INTO @db;
  END;

CLOSE crDB;
DEALLOCATE crDB;
```

Or you can get rid of the inner cursor altogether and use sys.sp_MSforeachtable:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
  SET @cmd = 'USE [' + @db + ']
    GO;
    EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = ''UPDATE STATISTICS ?;''';

  EXEC (@cmd);
```

Comment: Thx, looks like it's exactly what i'm looking for. Had to make a few small changes and testing it now.